# Reactjs -Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import {Jumbotron} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css'

export default class Form extends React.Component{

state={
    user:[],
    firstname:'',
    lastname:'',
}
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({firstname:event.target.value});
    this.setState({lastname:event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit = event =>{
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post('http://9795ca45.ngrok.io/api/Docs',{
        fname:this.state.firstname,
        lname:this.state.lastname
    })
    .then( res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        alert(error);
    })
}

componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://9795ca45.ngrok.io/api/Docs')
    .then(res =>{
        const data=res.data;

        const user = data.data;

        this.setState({user});
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        alert(error);
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Jumbotron>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    firstName:
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </label>
                <label>
                    LastName:
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </label>
                    <button type="submit">add</button>
                    </form>
            
                <h1> names </h1>
                <ul> {this.state.user.map(person => <li> {person.lname}</li>)}</ul>
                </Jumbotron>
                </div>
    )
}
}
```

am very new to reatjs
am trying to post the data to the url but am getting request not found 500 error
and i see this using debugger

**Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `Form`.**

please help me to come away from this

am getting the data from the url
but i unable to post the data

please check it and correct my code with an explanation

Comment: Use this: `{this.state.user.map((person, i) => <li key={i}> {person.lname}</li>)}`

Comment: am getting an error after clicking the button.. while trying to post..

Comment: previous question is to ask about get the data.. this time am facing the problem while posting the data.

Comment: Which previous question?

Comment: previous question is solved ..  whenever am trying to post only am geting request status failed 500 error

Comment: You are answering "previous question" when I am asking you what you mean by "previous question"... Do you mean your post has been answered? In that case post a new question please.

Comment: yes previous question is answered.. this is a new question but in the same program..  the question i was unable to post the data, am getting request not found 500 error

Comment: Alright, but your title is about unique key prop. What you have here is not relevant to that error. So please either modify your original question or post a new one.

Answer (score 4):

As written [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

You need to add a key to the list you are rendering inside a map.
you'r code should look like this:

```
<ul> {this.state.user.map(person => <li key={person.lname}> {person.lname}</li>)}</ul>
```

I would recommend setting the key as a unique ID and not the last name as it isn't unique for each person.

Comment: better to use the index as the key to guarantee uniqueness in that case.

Comment: this line is working and its fetching the data.

Comment: i am facing the problem in posting the data.. request not found error is arising whenever i clicked the button

Comment: @Chris as I read you shouldn't be using index in any case, am I wrong?

Comment: @SriHariKarthikVijayakumar this sounds like a different problem and not a one that relates to this issue. Check if the server really has an endpoint on post for the url you are sending you'r request to.

Comment: @MatanBobi, using indexes **can** be anti-pattern, but it depends on the use-case. Indexes guarantee uniqueness among keys (which avoids key collision) and is always better than using keys that *might* collide (like last name). The only time indexes as key is bad is when you rearrange the items in the array or add items to it (except when adding as last item aka push)